# Found photography: what is the status of a memory card?

Tags: legal, memory-card, used-equipment

All of my CF cards are pre-used, as I mainly shoof film, it's not worth the cost to get new ones. However, some of them have photos from the previous owner; what is the legal and artistic status of these images in the US?

Answer (score 4):

The default status of photographs is automatically that they're under copyright and unless you have some sort of license agreement with the person who made them, it would be illegal for you to publish them, modify them or do pretty much anything except look at them.

Comment: Pardon my nitpicking, but what if there were reasonable doubt, or other factors which made it quite unlikely that there is a copyright.

Comment: @Noah As Michael says, _copyright is the default_. If the ownership status is hard to determine, the unfortunate fact is that the photos live in a sort of legal limbo where nothing can be done. See the [wikipedia article on Orphan Works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_works) for more, and particularly [Orphan works in the United States](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_works_in_the_United_States)

Comment: @Noah: Pretty much the only way in which it would be possible for there to be no copyright would be if the photographs don't show a "minimal degree of creativity" - and I don't think you'd be interested in doing anything with them if that were the case. If in doubt, ask a lawyer.

Comment: What if one acquires what appear to be original uncopied media (e.g. photographic reversal films), either by inheritance or by inclusion within a purchased lot of goods?  Would one be entitled to assume, in the absence of indications to the contrary, that the inheritance or purchase of the films constituted inheritance or purchase of rights stemming therefrom?  Would digital memory cards be considered different because--unlike films--they are are often not the "primary" storage medium for the pictures that were originally stored on them?

Comment: @supercat The onus would be on you to make sure you are acquiring _rights_ and not just a copy before trying to profit or publish.  If you do profit or publish and find they are copyrighted by someone other than the seller, you are liable.

Comment: @DavidWilkins: If someone acquires a 100% interest in the property of a dead person or defunct business, and during the liquidation of the property materials are discovered which appear to have been created by that person or business, then any copyright interest that person or business had would transfer to the new owner, but I can't imagine any way anyone could ever prove that the owner of the materials hadn't transferred copyright to someone else.  I would think it very rare for anyone to sell unmarked original films without transferring copyright to the images thereon, since...

Comment: ...there wouldn't much the purchaser could do with them if rights weren't included; if the intention was to e.g. sell original slides for viewing purposes only, there's no reason the seller shouldn't mark the frames to indicate that intention.

Comment: @supercat The rub in your first comment is the assumption the memory card has not been copied. There is no way to tell by examining the memory card itself. It would be quite possible that the images were copied and saved by the original photographer. It could even be feasible that they were registered with the U.S. Copyright Office. Perhaps the owner meant to erase the cards before transferring ownership of the digital media. In the absence of a *clear* and *intentional* statement that the transfer of ownership of the memory cards included rights to the images one must assume it did not.

Comment: @MichaelClark: Different media differ in the likelihood of copies existing; for digital media, the probability would be much greater than with e.g. movies or slides on camera reversal film. My point was that an answer applicable to memory cards may not be applicable to other kinds of photographic media.

Comment: Also, there isn't even proof that the photographer INTENDED to make these images available to anyone - the card might have been stolen at some point, or found and sold, or be re-marketed customer returns, or resold by someone liquidating stuff that belonged to someone who died, pawned or carelessly abandoned it  ...